# Uploading image to GCS through REST / Endpoints API

Tags: google-app-engine, rest, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-endpoints

I have what I think is a common use case, but I can't find sample code.

I'm running on Google App Engine.

I want to:

1. Upload an image from a mobile client to a REST API (preferably powered by Endpoints)
2. Store that in Google Cloud Storage
3. Retrieve the storage URL
4. Store that URL in Datastore.

Would greatly appreciate if someone had an example of doing at least the first 2 or 3 steps :)

Comment: What GAE language runtime are you using?

Comment: Did you read the documentation? And if you did, what exactly is not clear?